# server.register error in hapi

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

I was learning hapijs for my new project. I am stuck at server.register() method. I believe I am doing everything right but yet I am getting error that  "Cannot read property 'register' of undefined" . Please help. Thanx in advance

```
    const hapi=require('hapi');
const server=new hapi.Server();

//Add connection
server.connection({
    port:4500,
    host:'localhost'
});

//creating route

server.route({
    method:'GET',
    path:'/',
    handler:(req,reply)=>{
        reply('Succ`enter code here`essfully created first route');
    }
});

//dynamic route
server.route({
    method:'GET',
    path:'/user/{id}',
    handler:(req,reply)=>{
        reply(`<p>User : ${req.params.id}</p>`)
    }
})

//static route

server.register(require('inert'),(err)=>{
    if(err)throw err;
    server.route({
        method:'GET',
        path:'/about',
        handler:(req,reply)=>{
            reply.file('./public/index.html')
        }
    })
})

//Start connection
server.start().then(
    ()=>console.log(`Server is running at ${server.info.uri}`)
).catch(
    err=>{throw err} 
)
```

Comment: can u please tell me the version of you inert plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be issue with plugin and hapi version incompatibility. Try using following version and it will work fine.

```
"hapi": "^16.6.2",
"inert": "^4.2.1",
```